# Sweave-generated pdf-figure has two pages instead of one, with the first being empty

Tags: r, sweave

Using `Sweave()` in R I am trying to include a `ggplot2`-graphic generated by `marrangeGrob()` from the R package `gridExtra` into a pdf document.

The problem occuring is that the pdf containing the figure included by the tex-document out of `Sweave()` has two pages, leaving the first page empty. The plot appears only on the second page. Therefore the figure won't appear in a pdf generated by the tex-file out of `Sweave()`.

The following is the content of an Rnw-file illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{My first plot}
\author{}

\begin{document}

<<fig=TRUE, width=7, height=7>>=
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x=factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), replace=TRUE, size=150)),
y=rnorm(150), z=factor(sample(c("a1", "a2"), replace=TRUE, size=150)))

library("ggplot2")
p1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() + ylab("y")
p2 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=z, fill=x)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge") + xlab("a1 or a2") +
theme(legend.position=c(0.8,0.8))

library("gridExtra")
grobframe <- marrangeGrob(list(p1, p2), ncol=2, nrow=1, top=NULL)

grobframe
@

\end{document}
```

How is it possible to prevent that the pdf containing the figure has two pages, where the first in empty, in order to make the plot show up in the final document?

Comment: Perhaps the image is too big to fit on the first page? Have you tried scaling it down?

Comment: I tried to vary width and height in <<fig=TRUE, width=7, height=7>>=, but that didn't help. Or did you mean a different procedure?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant (although I don't have any idea about Sweave). DO you get any warnings when processing your document? If so, could you add it(them) to your question?

Comment: You code as is runs fine with everything 'code' and 'both plots' on a single page.  I used knitr instead of sweave.  Read http://yihui.name/knitr/ for manuals and examples.

Comment: @ Gonzalo Medina: thanks, but unfortunately there are no warnings or error messages.  @ R.Schumacher: thanks, that sounds good, I will try with knitr and report on whether I got it to work.

Comment: With knit I got it to work, in the minimal example above, as well as in my actual code, thank you both again!

Comment: @R.Schumacher Sounds like you have the answer. WOuld you like to turn the comment into a proper answer?

Comment: @ R.Schumacher I flagged your answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting from Sweave to knitr, there are some syntax differences.  If you have running Sweave code blocks in an `*.Rnw` file then you can.

1. Open R
2. Change directory to the location of the `*.Rnw` file
3. Load the package `knitr` with library('knitr')
4. Now run the command `Sweave2knitr("*.Rnw")`
5. This will create a file called `*-knitr.Rnw` that now has correct knitr commands.

For this question the *-knitr.Rnw file is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\title{My first plot}
\author{}

\begin{document}

<<width='7in', height='7in'>>=
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(x=factor(sample(c("yes", "no"), replace=TRUE, size=150)),
y=rnorm(150), z=factor(sample(c("a1", "a2"), replace=TRUE, size=150)))

library("ggplot2")
p1 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip() + ylab("y")
p2 <- ggplot(data=data, aes(x=z, fill=x)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge") + xlab("a1 or a2") +
theme(legend.position=c(0.8,0.8))

library("gridExtra")
grobframe <- marrangeGrob(list(p1, p2), ncol=2, nrow=1, top=NULL)

grobframe
@

\end{document}
```

Either using the R-console or in my case a tailored user-command in TeXmaker, you need to first run `knit` on the above file, which results in an `*.tex` file.

Now you simple do a normal LaTeX compile.

The very important points to remember. Only edit the *.Rnw file, and you must re-knit it before a new LaTeX compile.

The output from the above code is:
[image]